# How do I use nested templates in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to C++ and doing a class in it now. As homework, we are supposed to write a function that accepts any container as input but does not use iterators. So we are not allowed to just pass `std::begin(container)` and `std::end(container)` as arguments. We have to pass the containers as references. My take on this was the following function declaration:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, template <typename a, typename b> typename container>
void doStuff(container<T, U>& first, container<T, V>& second)
{
    // the code
}
```

It accepts two containers (or any templated type that uses two template arguments). The second template argument in `container` is different since in arrays `V` might represent the size of the array and I want to be able to accept two arrays of different sizes.

Example:

```
std::array<bool, 4> a1 = { true, false, false, false };
std::array<bool, 1> a2 = { false };
```

Unfortunately, this example does not work. The error says that I `doStuff` does not accept arguments of these types. Why is that?

In my opinion, using a "templated template" here is important, because I would like to make sure that the function only accepts two containers if they contain the same kind of data. So passing an int array and a double array should not work.

Comment: The second parameter of `std::array` is a number, not a type.

Comment: So `size_t U, size_t V` would work? How can I make sure that I have a solution that accepts containers where the second argument is a number (arrays) and containers were the second argument is an allocator?

Comment: You say you are not allowed pointers and then say that rules out `std::begin(container)`. But `std::begin(container)` returns an *iterator*, *not* a pointer. So that makes little sense.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant iterator. You are right @JesperJuhl

Comment: Why not just take `FirstContainer& first, SecondContainer& second`? This could actually take *any* container.

Comment: I thought about that @Horstling. As far as I get C++ templating it would not be possible to make sure that `FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer` contain the same kind of data. Or am I wrong? What I want to avoid is that FirstContainer is e.g. vector<int> and that `SecondContainer` ist `vector<double>`. This is why I used a "templated template".

Comment: I'd say `FirstContainer, SecondContainer` is pretty much the idiomatic approach to this (keep in mind that there are many containers in all sorts of flavors, they might not even be templates). If your code doesn't work with mismatching value types, it will cause an compile error eventually. Or you could explicitly check value types using `static_assert` or SFINAE.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for pointing that out @Horstling. I only know a few containers and I think all of the ones I know are templated (again I am new to C++). Could you please write your comment as an answer? I would like to have a look a the code version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to support as many container types as possible, you should use the least restricting definition possible:

```
template <typename FirstContainer, typename SecondContainer>
void doStuff(FirstContainer& first, SecondContainer& second)
{
}
```

This is because container types come in all sort of flavors, e.g. `std::array` is a template taking a value type and a static size as argument, `std::vector` is a template taking a value type and an allocator, some custom `StringList` might not be a template at all.

Your implementation might have some specific requirements to the supported containers, e.g. it might only work for containers of integer types. But more often than not this is just an implicit result of the implementation. Take for a example a simple function summing up values of two containers:

```
template <typename FirstContainer, typename SecondContainer>
int sum(const FirstContainer& first, const SecondContainer& second)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (auto value : first)
        result += value;
    for (auto value : second)
        result += value;
    return result;
}
```

This function works fine with any value types that can be added to an integer. If it can't be added (like a `std::string`), it will cause a compilation error eventually.

(Note that one could write this function even more generic with an automatically deduced sum type instead of just `int`)

If these "implicit requirements" are not enough for you, you can add explicit checks using `static_assert`:

```
template <typename FirstContainer, typename SecondContainer>
int sum(const FirstContainer& first, const SecondContainer& second)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (auto value : first)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(value)>, "FirstContainer does not hold integers");
        result += value;
    }
    for (auto value : second)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(value)>, "SecondContainer does not hold integers");
        result += value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now your function is only accepting containers holding plain `int`, nothing else.

You can also use `std::enable_if` to completely "disable" your function for non-supported containers:

```
template <typename FirstContainer, typename SecondContainer>
auto sum(const FirstContainer& first, const SecondContainer& second)
    -> std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<typename FirstContainer::value_type, int> &&
        std::is_same_v<typename SecondContainer::value_type, int>,
        int
    >
{
    int result = 0;
    for (auto value : first)
        result += value;
    for (auto value : second)
        result += value;
    return result;
}
```

Now your function is restricted to containers with a nested typedef `value_type` to type `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will wait a few days before accepting it as a solution since I would like to see other ideas (if there are any).